# Launchy opens editor instead of browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm using gem `launchy` and `capybara`. When `save_and_open_page` is executed, it opens page not in browser but in my editor (Sublime Text). How can I change this behaviour and why is it's happening?
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: what default app for open `html` page?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a system-wide preference set to open .html files with Sublime. Changing that should take care of this.

Comment: Yes, changing preference helps. But is there a way to manually define application for `save_and_open_page`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `save_page` and redefine `save_and_open_page`

```
def save_and_open_page
  `sublime #{save_page}`
end
```

You must to include the new method in your spec file and you can take opportunity to make it shorter like `saop` for example.

Comment: Neat! (In OS X, this works with the `subl` symlink which first needs to be set up as per [instructions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).)